# Removing whitespaces from encrypted data

Tags: php, whitespace, mcrypt, strlen

I have a function for decrypt earlier decrypted data:

```
public function Decrypt($encrypedText) {
    $key = "The secret key is";
    $decryptedText = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($encrypedText), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    $trimmedData = rtrim($decryptedText, '\0');

    echo strlen($trimmedData);          // 32

    return $trimmedData;
}
```

If I put in "Test" in the function, the outcome will be "Test" + 28 white spaces. I got the tips from someone who told me to use "rtrim" as done in the function above to remove the white spaces, but that doesn't seem to work (when I check the length of the outcome it's still 32).

What can I do to remove these white spaces?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `trim()`?

Comment: Have you tried the trim() without the second argument?  Doing so will strip all whitespace characters and not just the NUL-byte character that you had specified. `$trimmedData = rtrim($decryptedText);`http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: @Buggabill: Convert your comment to an answer (or write a new one) and I'll accept it, cuz it solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) without the second argument.  This will strip a host of whitespace characters and not just the NUL-byte character that you had specified..

```
$trimmedData = rtrim($decryptedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, trim() should work. Try regular expression:

```
$string = preg_replace('~\s+$~', '', $string);
```

Comment: Tried it, and it still contains of 32 chars :/

Comment: That proves that those characters are not whitespaces. Save output string to a file, and view it with hex editor...

Comment: Point taken! Is there another way to view string without saving it to a file?

Comment: try this function strToHex($string) { $hex=''; for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {$hex .= '%' . dechex(ord($string[$i])); } return $hex; }   // and show me what the output is